# Java Stream API

Tags: java, list, lambda, java-8, java-stream

When we get Stream from a List of Collections, what actually happens under the hood? I found in many blogs saying that Stream doesn't store any data. If it's true, consider the snippet of code:

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
list.add(1);
list.add(2);
list.add(3);

Stream<Integer> stream = list.stream();
list = null;
stream.forEach(i -> System.out.print(i));
```

As we can see, elements are accessible to stream even if List (source) is `null`.
How is this possible?

Comment: I don't know how streams work internally, but setting that reference to null doesn't really show anything. The stream probably holds its own reference to the data, meaning setting `list` to `null` just made the data unavailable in that scope.

Answer (score 1):

The Stream API has no idea what is inside the `List` until the lambda expression is performed over the first and remaining elements.

```
stream.forEach(i -> System.out.print(i));
```

The code above is nothing else than a shortcut for:

```
stream.forEach(new Consumer<String>() {
    @Override
    public void accept(String t) {
        System.out.println(t);
    }
});
```

The lambda expression is just an implemented interface, the functional interface which has only and only one method. This special interface is annotated with [`@FunctionalInterface`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/FunctionalInterface.html)  and could be expressed as a lambda expression.

The point is, the method `accept(String t)` doesn't execute before it's actually called - the same happens for the lambda. Consider the following:

```
Consumer<String> consumer = i -> System.out.print(i);

// At this point the method `System.out.print(i)` remains not executed.
// Whatever expensive operation inside any lambda remains unexecuted 
// until its only method is called

stream.forEach(consumer);   // Now it encounters all the elements
```

For this reason, the Stream has no idea about the elements because it leaves the entire execution to the passed lambda expressions.

---

By the way setting `list = null` doesn't affect anything since the `Stream<Integer>` has already been created. The source is stored as [`Spliterator<T>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Spliterator.html) in [`AbstractPipeline` (line 123)](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/util/stream/AbstractPipeline.java).

Answer (score 1):

This has little to do with Streams per-se, a very much simplified example:

```
 static class Holder {
    private final List<Integer> list;

    public Holder(List<Integer> list) {
        this.list = list;
    }

    public void show() {
        list.forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}

 Holder h = new Holder(list);
 list = null;
 h.show();
```

This simply re-assigns a reference, nothing more.

Comment: Thumbs up for not getting lost in streams, but pointing out that it is just a question of reference vs value and that the list still exists.

Comment: In above example you are assigning the reference to the member variable(list) and nullifying the parameter(list), which is perfectly fine & works as expected. But in my example, I'm trying to nullify the source which the stream is pointing to. In some tutorials they said that, stream is meant for processing elements but doesn't store any. If it's true, how I am able reference the elements even if the source that stream points to is marked as NULL.

Comment: @AnoopDeshpande you are nullifying the *reference*, not the source. and when you call `stream()` there will be a *new* reference pointing to the same *source*, internally that reference will be used